# How can I use dynamic latitude and longitude values in a Google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps API. From here I have one array, `locations`, from which I have latitude and longitude values. Based on these values I am creating a route. The locations variable is given static latitude and longitude values. Instead of static values I want to give dynamic latitude and longitude values. I don't know how make this dynamic. Can anyone help me please/

```js
var res = {
  "loginType": "logout",
  "status": "success",
  "count": 1,
  "absentCount": 2,
  "startingLat": "12.9817121",
  "startingLng": "77.72649609999996",
  "companyLat": "12.9563031",
  "companyLng": "77.6949695",
  "data": [{
      "empName": "Trisha",
      "pickupTime": "07:45 AM",
      "cabName": "Atios",
      "pickupLatitude": "13.0180851",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.76444330000004",
    },
    {
      "empName": "Divya",
      "pickupTime": "08:45 AM",
      "cabName": "Atios",
      "pickupLatitude": "13.01807777",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.764443308884",
    },
  ],
  "travlledLocation": [{
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956664",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.696829"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956604",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.696480"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956523",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.696021"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956413",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.695380"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956335",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.695029"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956230",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694997"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956107",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694994"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.955934",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694970"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.955639",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694932"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.955380",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694902"
    }
  ]
}



var geocoder;
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var locations = [
  ['Start', 12.956664, 77.696829, 1],
  ['2', 12.956604, 77.696480, 2],
  ['3', 12.956523, 77.696021, 3],
  ['4', 12.956413, 77.695380, 4],
  ['5', 12.956335, 77.695029, 5],
  ['6', 12.956230, 77.694997, 6],
  ['7', 12.956107, 77.694994, 7],
  ['8', 12.955934, 77.694970, 8],
  ['9', 12.955639, 77.694932, 9],
  ['End', 12.955380, 77.694902, 10]
];


var waypoints = [{
    "empName": "arun",
    "pickupTime": "9:10 AM",
    "lat": "12.956604",
    "lng": "77.696480",

  },
  {
    "empName": "babu",
    "pickupTime": "9:40 AM",
    "lat": "12.956230",
    "lng": "77.694997",
  },
  {
    "empName": "sharma",
    "pickupTime": "9:55 AM",
    "lat": "12.955639",
    "lng": "77.694932",
  }
];


function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });


  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25), // 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var request = {
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if (locations[i][3] == 1 || locations[i][3] == locations.length) {

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        i: locations[i][0]
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(marker.i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, infowindow));

    if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
    else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();


  }
  //push the waypoints to request.waypoints array
  waypoints.forEach(function(v, i) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat, v.lng),
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-56165014858e6dbadaf3ba00d782f125.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 45)
      },
      data: v
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<b>Employee Name : </b>' + marker.data.empName + '<br><b>pickupTime : </b>' + marker.data.pickupTime);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, infowindow));
  })

  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

I need to make dynamic lat & lng values from `res.travlledLocation` and change them to this format:

```
 var locations = [
  ['Start', 12.956664, 77.696829, 1],
  ['2', 12.956604, 77.696480, 2],
  ['3', 12.956523, 77.696021, 3],
  ['4', 12.956413, 77.695380, 4],
  ['5', 12.956335, 77.695029, 5],
  ['6', 12.956230, 77.694997, 6],
  ['7', 12.956107, 77.694994, 7],
  ['8', 12.955934, 77.694970, 8],
  ['9', 12.955639, 77.694932, 9],
  ['End', 12.955380, 77.694902, 10]
];
```

> my waypoint marker it has to come like this

[My Waypoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNxOU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired 2D array from the `travlledLocation` array of objects you can use `map()`, like this:

```
var locations = res.travlledLocation.map(function(o, i) {
  return [
    i == 0 ? 'Start' : i == res.travlledLocation.length - 1 ? 'End' : i,
    o.Travlinglatitude,
    o.Travlinglongitude,
    i + 1
  ]
});
```

```js
var res = {
  "loginType": "logout",
  "status": "success",
  "count": 1,
  "absentCount": 2,
  "startingLat": "12.9817121",
  "startingLng": "77.72649609999996",
  "companyLat": "12.9563031",
  "companyLng": "77.6949695",
  "data": [{
      "empName": "Trisha",
      "pickupTime": "07:45 AM",
      "cabName": "Atios",
      "pickupLatitude": "13.0180851",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.76444330000004",
    },
    {
      "empName": "Divya",
      "pickupTime": "08:45 AM",
      "cabName": "Atios",
      "pickupLatitude": "13.01807777",
      "pickupLongitude": "77.764443308884",
    },
  ],
  "travlledLocation": [{
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956664",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.696829"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956604",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.696480"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956523",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.696021"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956413",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.695380"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956335",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.695029"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956230",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694997"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.956107",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694994"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.955934",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694970"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.955639",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694932"
    },
    {
      "Travlinglatitude": "12.955380",
      "Travlinglongitude": "77.694902"
    }
  ]
}

var geocoder;
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var locations = res.travlledLocation.map(function(o, i) {
  return [
    i == 0 ? 'Start' : i == res.travlledLocation.length - 1 ? 'End' : i,
    o.Travlinglatitude,
    o.Travlinglongitude,
    i + 1
  ]
});

var waypoints = res.data.map(function(o) {
  return {
    empName: o.empName,
    pickupTime: o.pickupTime,
    lat: o.pickupLatitude,
    lng: o.pickupLongitude
  }
});

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25), // 
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var request = {
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    if (locations[i][3] == 1 || locations[i][3] == locations.length) {

      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        i: locations[i][0]
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(marker.i);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, infowindow));

    if (i == 0) request.origin = marker.getPosition();
    else if (i == locations.length - 1) request.destination = marker.getPosition();


  }
  //push the waypoints to request.waypoints array
  waypoints.forEach(function(v, i) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(v.lat, v.lng),
      map: map,
      icon: {
        url: 'http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-56165014858e6dbadaf3ba00d782f125.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(45, 45)
      },
      data: v
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent('<b>Employee Name : </b>' + marker.data.empName + '<br><b>pickupTime : </b>' + marker.data.pickupTime);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, infowindow));
  })

  directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7lDrYPDmJz1JsQh2rbWA9uRZHcFk_xJY">
</script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Mr@Rory McCrossan. I tried your code but map is not displaying,can please update all answer and put in snippet

Comment: I updated the answer for you with an example. The issue was because the example array you showed was missing the final parameter.

Comment: Actually waypoints array also i given in static values can you please make that also dynamic that empName&pickupTime coming from data array (res variable)

Comment: You can use the same logic. I updated the answer again. Note that the waypoints are being added, you just need to zoom the map out to see them

Comment: Yes they are, you need to zoom out, as I mentioned.

Comment: I tried but marker is not displaying, i need waypoint marker has to display

Comment: ***Again*** - they are being displayed, but you need to **zoom out**. https://i.imgur.com/b5JbLh1.png. If they're not showing where you expect them, you need to fix your data. The JS logic is working perfectly.

Comment: Please check this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNxOU.png,  my waypoint marker should come like this,i am giving static lat & lng values it is working ,when applying dynamic waypoint it is not working

Comment: I don't know if you're not understanding what I'm saying, but the example I gave is working with the `data` array in the `res` object ***you provided*** -
 exactly as your question asked. The information in `data` is different to the static array you stored in the `waypoints` array you had in the question - hence the output is different. I don't understand your confusion here.

Comment: Phew :) glad we got there in the end